# Knockout object passed to Controller as JSon MVC ASP.Net

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js

I am trying to pass knockout object as below,
When i pass the data using // ko.utils.postJson only without any  the AJAx the data is passed to my controller to the "task", but when i try to post by Ajax I get a null value for task

```
   function TaskListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableMeals = [
   { UserName: "Standard", UserId: 0 },
   { UserName: "Premium", UserId: 34 },
   { UserName: "Ultimate", UserId: 290 }
    ];


         self.save = function () {

         // ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { task: this.availableMeals }); 


          $.ajax(location.href,{

                data: ko.toJSON({ task: this.availableMeals });,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) { alert(result) }
            });
    };



    }

   ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

To the Controller as below,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About([FromJson] IEnumerable<UserProfile> task)
    {
          return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of... task: this.availableMeals when it is being posted. Is it valid json.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing your code to call the stored self reference in your Ajax call as follows:

```
$.ajax(location.href,{
       data: ko.toJSON({ task: self.availableMeals });,
       type: 'POST',
       dataType:'json',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       success: function (result) { alert(result) }
    });
};
```

I'm guessing that you are having a scope issues where `this` is losing it's reference in your Ajax call.

Comment: The content type caused the data to not pass when I removed the content type it passed BUT when the controller recives JSON we can see that 3 objects are recived but the UserName and UserId are strill null. Thanks for respond